# Mysql Query Weird Resultset When Querying by YEAR

Tags: mysql

Ok so here is my issue. I'm trying to get number of albums per month throughout the years. 
This is my query

```
SELECT DATE(a.date), COUNT(a.id) 
FROM album a 
JOIN event e ON e.id = a.event_id  
WHERE  YEAR(a.date) >= 2001 
AND e.client_id = 89 
GROUP BY MONTH(a.date) 
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

The result returned is

```
+--------------+-------------+
| DATE(a.date) | COUNT(a.id) |
+--------------+-------------+
| 2011-09-09   |          15 |
| 2011-08-26   |           9 |
| 2010-01-01   |          28 |
| 2006-03-03   |          20 |
| 2005-12-02   |          20 |
| 2005-11-11   |          15 |
| 2005-10-07   |          13 |
| 2005-07-01   |          12 |
| 2005-06-03   |           6 |
| 2005-05-06   |          18 |
| 2005-04-15   |          15 |
| 2005-02-04   |          22 |
+--------------+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This result set is missing results for 2012
But if I write this

```
SELECT DATE(a.date), COUNT(a.id)
FROM album a 
JOIN event e ON e.id = a.event_id 
WHERE 
YEAR(a.date) > 2005
AND e.client_id = 89 GROUP BY MONTH(a.date)
ORDER BY a.date DESC;
```

And now I get 2012 but I'm missing 2005 :/ Can anybody explain this to me please?

```
+--------------+-------------+
| DATE(a.date) | COUNT(a.id) |
+--------------+-------------+
| 2012-06-01   |           2 |
| 2012-05-04   |          14 |
| 2012-04-06   |          13 |
| 2011-12-02   |          10 |
| 2011-11-04   |           9 |
| 2011-10-07   |          10 |
| 2011-09-09   |           9 |
| 2011-08-26   |           6 |
| 2010-01-01   |          26 |
| 2006-07-07   |           8 |
| 2006-03-03   |          19 |
| 2006-02-03   |          16 |
+--------------+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: please check your WHERE `YEAR(a.date) > 2005` .... use `YEAR(a.date) > 2004` or `>=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by `MONTH` so I believe all your yearly data is being combined into one count (notice you get 12 rows each time, 1 for each month).  I think you can fix that by grouping by year and month...

```
GROUP BY YEAR(a.date)
GROUP BY MONTH(a.date)
```

(for the first case anyway, for the second case you won't get 2005 data by calling `year > 2005`, as silly pointed out)

Comment: Thank you guys!!! Saved my head from banging in the wall :)  Thank you!!! Really appreciate this.